# barman + mark the failed/started backup with red color

Tags: linux, bash, backup, tput, barman

With the following barman command we can see the backup status, while  STARTED/FAILED status indicated that backup inst created successfully

```
barman list-backup main-db-server
```

Output:

```
main-db-server 20170913T115706 - STARTED
main-db-server 20170913T115214 - STARTED
main-db-server 20170913T114659 - STARTED
main-db-server 20170912T233003 - FAILED
main-db-server 20170912T145147 - Tue Sep 12 14:51:50 2017 - Size: 45.2 MiB - WAL Size: 68.6 KiB
main-db-server 20170912T140611 - Tue Sep 12 14:06:14 2017 - Size: 41.2 MiB - WAL Size: 6.3 MiB
main-db-server 20170912T140430 - Tue Sep 12 14:04:36 2017 - Size: 41.2 MiB - WAL Size: 38.6 KiB
```

Is it possible in some way to pipe after the the barman syntax the tput command in order to marked the lines with FAILED/STARTED with red color, so the user can identify this lines as bad backup's?

Example:

```
barman list-backup main-db-server |  ... tput setaf 1  ... tput sgr0
```

remark - "**tput setaf 1**"  --> will paint the characters with red

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep for that

`barman list-backup main-db-server |  grep -E 'FAILED|STARTED' |   ... tput setaf 1  ... tput sgr0`